# PHP comparing files checksum or deeper

Tags: php, file, comparison

Good day,

I am having a complicated question (at least for me it is)
Have been asked to create a system that upload engine management files and compare the engine management file to engine management files already available in the system. And check if there are any matching files. So to say a specific engine supplied by Audi is also being used by Seat and so it returns a match.

But I have no experience in file comparison as such.
Are there any tools available?

Possible tools that can also give me a matching percentage. For example : matches for about 73%.

TIAD!

**P.S. the reason for my very minimal question, already performed searches is that I also do NOT know exactly what search terms to look for. So even that would be a good kick in the right direction**

Comment: You probably want to tell more what *engine management file* is, e.g. is it a text, or binary, average size,  etc. The % comparison also requires a bit of details. At least which metrics you want to compare.

Comment: If engine management files are *not* binary file, have a look on [xdiff_file_diff function](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.xdiff-file-diff.php)

Comment: Agree with @AlexBlex- you need to talk about your filetype in your question. Say it is XML then you will tell us you already searched for `php diff xml` (`diff` is your keyword for file compare) and then ask about next steps after you tried to do something...

Answer (score 0):

### Checksum

You may want to look for the **[hash_file()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-file.php)** function:

```
<?php

$firstFile = '/tmp/foo.jpg';
$secondFile = '/tmp/bar.jpg';

$algo = 'md5';

if (hash_file($algo, $firstFile) === hash_file($algo, $secondFile)) {
    // files should be the same
}
```

### Matching percentage

The **[similar_text()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php)** function answer your issue:

```
<?php

$var1 = 'foobar';
$var2 = 'foo';

similar_text($var1, $var2, $percent);

var_dump($percent)
// 66.66
```

### General PHP algorithm

So, combined with the **[file_get_contents()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)** function, you should have something like:

```
<?php

$firstFile = '/tmp/foo.txt';
$secondFile = '/tmp/bar.txt';

$algo = 'md5';

$firstContent = file_get_contents($firstFile);
$secondContent = file_get_contents($secondFile);

if (hash_file($algo, $firstFile) === hash_file($algo, $secondFile)) {
    // files should be the same
} elseif (similar_text($firstContent, $secondContent, $percent)) {
    // files are similar with `$percent` %...
}
```

### Assumption

I assume you will modify `$firstFile`, `$secondFile` and `$algo` variables in order to make the pieces of code working

### Future tracks

You may want to ease access to this piece of code as so:

```
<?php

/**
 * Compare two files
 *
 * @param string $first  First file path
 * @param string $second Second file path
 * @param string $algo   Checksum algorithm
 *
 * @return mixed Boolean true if files are the same, false if completely
 *               different and float number which represent the matching
 *               percentage otherwise.
 */
function compare_files($first, $second, $algo)
{
    if (hash_file($algo, $first) === hash_file($algo, $second)) {
        return true;
    }
    $first = file_get_contents($first);
    $second = file_get_contents($second);
    if (similar_text($first, $second, $percent)) {
        return $percent;
    }
    return false;
}

// ========================================================================= //

/**
 * Compare a reference file with files in an array
 *
 * @param string $ref  Reference file path
 * @param array  $arr  Array containing files to compare
 * @param string $algo Checksum algorithm
 */
function loop_comparison($ref, array $arr, $algo)
{
    foreach ($arr as $cur) {
        if (($res = compare_files($ref, $cur, $algo)) !== false) {
            if ($res === true) {
                echo $ref.' and '.$cur.' are the same files'.PHP_EOL;
            } else {
                echo $ref.' and '.$cur.' are '.$res.'% the same'.PHP_EOL;
            }
        } else {
            echo $ref.' and '.$cur.' are completely different'.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}

// ========================================================================= //

define('CHECKSUM_ALGO', 'md5');

$reference = 'file1.txt';
$to_compare = array(
    'file1.txt',
    'file2.txt',
    'file3.txt',
);

// ========================================================================= //

loop_comparison($reference, $to_compare, CHECKSUM_ALGO);
```

Which gives:

```
file1.txt and file1.txt are the same files
file1.txt and file2.txt are 17.340286831812% the same
file1.txt and file3.txt are completely different
```

Here, `file3.txt` is empty